# Is there a way to automatically extract chapters from Pdf files?

Tags: python

currently I am searching for a way to efficiently extract certain sections from around 500 pdf files.

Concretely, I have around 500 annual reports from which I want to extract the Management Report section.

I tried using a regular expression with the heading name as start position, and the following chapter as an ending position, but it (of course) always just yields the table of contents.

I am happy for any suggestions.

Comment: [PDFSyntax](https://github.com/desgeeko/pdfsyntax) was recently posted on [Hackernews](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=33646951). an older tool is [PDFMiner](https://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/pdfminer/index.html)

Comment: Hey there, thank you for the suggestion. Can you please elaborate on PDFMIner for this specific use case? As I have used PDFminer to convert it from pdf to txt, but the issue of the extraction of specific chapters still persists.

Comment: I would read the docs for more details. If you'd like a specific answer then I would add more detail and code to your post -- see [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)